# Redirect to Home Page using Nav Bar

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to add one button in Nav bar for redirect to index.php. Please Help me to complete the task.i want to redirect to this below url

http://localhost/Backup/web/index.php

i trying the below code,

```
     echo Nav::widget([
      'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
  'encodeLabels' => false,
      'items' => [
  ['label' => 'ContactUs', 'url' => ['index.php']],
    ],
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 'url'=> Yii::$app->homeUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo Nav::widget([
      'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
  'encodeLabels' => false,
      'items' => [
  ['label' => 'ContactUs', 'url' => ['web/index']],
    ],
  ]);
```

Comment: if i use like this the url is passed like below http://localhost/Backup/web/index.php?r=web/index

Comment: You need to modify url by using this  'enablePrettyUrl' => true in config file